# Unbracketing python array segments

Tags: python

```
A=["asd","jkl","qwe"]
[A[1:3],A[0:1]]
```

gives

```
[['jkl', 'qwe'], ['asd']]
```

I wish it just gave

```
['jkl', 'qwe', 'asd']
```

How do I accomplish this seemingly elusive task?

edit: the version of python I must work with does not allow for * symbol.

Comment: `[A[1], A[2], A[0]]`?? If you mean something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Timur Unless they're starting with already nested lists (doesn't look like it), I'd say the appropriate original would be one that's about doing what they want without building a nested list in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```py
A=["asd","jkl","qwe"]
A = [*A[1:3], *A[0:1]]
```

Comment: The version of python I must work with does not accept the * symbol.

Comment: `[A[1], A[2], A[0]]` then?